# Does Vim have a marketing symbol?

Tags: history-of

Since Vim is one of the most popular editors maybe it does not need marketing, but does it have a marketing symbol, like the Linux Penguin?

Comment: [A logo?](https://vim.sexy/img/Vimlogo.svg)

Comment: `Vim is one of the most popular editors` I definitely agree that it's the *best* editor, but are you sure [it's the most popular?](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-editor)

Comment: Or maybe you're talking about a mascot like this [little fella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Leaarning_the_vi_and_vim_editors.png).

Comment: @TommyA: I might be wrong but I think the little animal on the o'reilly book is not free unlike the logo linked by @ Tumbler41... Also I'm really not sure this question is on topic for this site...

Comment: @statox I just wanted to make people look at it 

Comment: Wondering about a logo has nothing to do with Vim's usage.

Comment: Logo should be `:q` (:half-troll:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

[image: Vim Logo]

Thanks Tumbler41 for the link.

Comment: I like how succinct this answer is.  With one word and a giant image, it has the grace of a ballerina driving a bulldozer through a glass factory.

Comment: [There](http://gfxmonk.net/images/vim-logo/vim-logo-128.png) [have](https://ohdoylerules.com/content/images/vim.svg) [been](http://amnoid.de/tmp/vim_solidbright_512.png) [a](https://macin.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/macvim-7-2-icon.png) [few](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2be2e1aa4c32e3f753b4ff0da314e57a76150b7d/687474703a2f2f636c2e6c792f696d6167652f3266326432653148326e32632f636f6e74656e74) [variations](http://wolfrosch.com/_img/works/goodies/icon/vim@2x).